# Using the values of 2 similar objects as an object map key -- implicit 'any' error

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to modify a piece of code to work with a new format of API response, whilst keeping compatibility with the old format. The responses are similar, it's mainly the keys that are different. I wrote a simple function that would get a property by using a map of the new key names to the old ones, but I am receiving a TypeScript error.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```js
type NewFormat = {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}

type OldFormat = {
  f: string;
  b: number;
}

const newData = {
  foo: "baz",
  bar: 12
}

const oldData = {
  f: "qux",
  b: 17
}

const barMap = {
  12: "TWELVE",
  17: "SEVENTEEN"
}

const shorthandPropertyMap: {
  [key in keyof NewFormat]: keyof OldFormat;
} = {
  foo: "f",
  bar: "b"
};

const getProperty = (
  data: NewFormat | OldFormat,
  prop: keyof typeof shorthandPropertyMap
) => {
  return prop in data
    ? (data as NewFormat)[prop]
    : (data as OldFormat)[shorthandPropertyMap[prop]!];
};

console.log(barMap[getProperty(oldData, "bar")] === "SEVENTEEN")
console.log(barMap[getProperty(newData, "bar") as keyof typeof barMap] === "TWELVE")
```

The first console log demonstrates the error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number' can't be used to index type '{ 12: string; 17: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ 12: string; 17: string; }'.
```

The second console log shows how I can work around it. However, I would prefer to improve the `getProperty()` function if possible. I've tried some generic approaches but nothing has worked.

[TypeScript Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDuAxA9gJwLYENhQLxQG8BYAKCigDNlkAuKAZ2FQEsA7AcwG5TyAjTVHVYBXdLwipuJAL6lSoSFADyAGwAmKDNjyEelOoxYcpfIaPGTSskqQDGyVoyisEAEWyYdxMpWp0ARPwAXv4ANHr8glAAjABMVnIk9o44yOruwJ743uQUAQCOwgAeYRF00QDsCTZJDk6RALKYYF56cQEAKgDqAKIAMgBqPaU+lQEAyj1DMB09PTD+1XZ1OPQAFmjAa5isagAKqMiQqKBNYHQ5UADaANYQIFBsUHcgyBRQewLAzJgqADxwJBoLDAAB8AF06C83sp1JoQVJpK0fFRaFB-BQRnwBAFeIsZFJlikoOwIMADkcJKAdAAKPRqDx0QHw7QAH1hGmB2HCPjAh3Oz3uMIUEBh602212FOOp2apAAlHhQbofKgycJUKwoHyjo8tQzMnpyAB+KA0g2eTD0WAIFnAeVXHVgcFGqB0c0eKBWjl2h3ik6S-b8qkgM6O-nggCE4MRhJqyXoaQgADoVMh2DTGs0rqTycGTiAaWk1BlMKF0ZF-PLwXhcPh-JNprN5lWiYmVCm0xms2Ac2TpSGaS54KXy4EBFWvdboe8RTCezW6-Xuv0hlWgA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w2z21w) meet your needs?  I've used [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) for a lot of your objects so the compiler knows exactly which keys go with which values, and the only [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) is used is to tell the compiler what type it can expect `prop in data ? prop : shorthandPropertyMap[prop]` to be.  If that works I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz it doesn't, but that's because I oversimplified my question. In my original source code, the `OldFormat` and `NewFormat` types have some additional properties with types like `number[]`, `string[]` and other complex types that cannot be used as keys, so the compiler complains about that instead. I appreciate the effort, though, it feels a step closer.

Comment: Could you fix the oversimplification by adding whatever is necessary to demonstrate why my proposed solution fails?  Like [this maybe](https://tsplay.dev/m36BLN) and then I could proceed with writing an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the data (here `newData` and `oldData`) is what you receive as your API response?

In that case, the root cause of the issue is that the data contains `string` or `number` *values*, but TypeScript sees them as *arbitrary* values, and it warns that this may not match the actual `barMap` keys (literal `12 | 17`).

As such, this cause is unrelated to your `getProperty` function, and should *already* affect your application even with just the old format:

```
const v1 = oldData["b"] // v1 is a number, which may not match any of the actual barMap keys
//    ^? number
barMap[oldData["b"]] // Error: No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type '{ 12: string; 17: string; }'.
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

There are several possible workarounds:

```
// Either loosen barMap to accept any number key type...
const barMap2: Record<number, string> = barMap

barMap2[oldData["b"]] // Okay, but of course it could be undefined in case there is no such key in barMap

// ...or restrict the data type with a const assertion
// (probably not do-able in practice if data is external)...
const oldData2 = {
  f: "",
  b: 12
} as const

barMap[oldData2["b"]] // Okay, and rejects if oldData2.b does not match any of barMap keys

// ...or make the data format type more specific
type OldFormat2 = {
  f: string
  b: keyof typeof barMap
}

// Since data comes from an external API, its type is asserted somewhere anyway.
// Of course its actual shape should still be validated in runtime.
declare const oldData3: OldFormat2

barMap[oldData3["b"]] // Okay
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gNgEwGIHsBOBbAhsKBeKAbwFgAoKKAMwC4oBnYNASwDsBzAbjIoCNaWArhh4Q0XUgF8yZAMYoWDKCkQARHFnxFuVWgCIAjgIAeugDTa+UAIwB2MlNKz5inljQBZLGE0ly1gEx6ACoA6gCiADIAamFm2rZ6AMphMQByQWFhqbr20qRyCrgAblaayghqwFgA2ro8ugC6UAD0zVAlUEx0UBqCwqKmUADuABZMMiNQ2CBQLCi42MATPSwzKJRQwCPQWDLAAlhwUK4eXlAA1hAgdGStFBQAegD8ToXt-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-oBGhyISTLghgKxQKBogQVAACCAAKACSgxYt0VnAXhx7Eq2dAoISozdisIBDPmcrybAGzlmglbpT0ewHEcdAjF4xkjCytYMEwcBHCI7SHEwgEtm2aCsqehIVXCMhwG40AHko8FYHGtA2agenADhs4LUUACsZFeBR-xxhmQJ0bADGToqSlAA)

---

Now if we keep the approach of using more specific format types, since we have to assert the external data at some point anyway:

- We can have `getProperty` working by using a generic type to infer the type of the actually requested property
- The `shorthandPropertyMap` converter must be asserted as const, so that TS uses the values as literals, and they can be matched against the `OldFormat` keys; it is still possible to constrain this converter to associate keys of the New and Old Formats if we use the new `satisfies` operator coming in next TS version (4.9)

```
// Using the more restrictive data format type approach
type NewFormat = {
  foo: string;
  bar: keyof typeof barMap;
}

type OldFormat = {
  f: string;
  b: keyof typeof barMap;
}

// data would come from an external API,
// so it is asserted somewhere, but should still
// be validated at runtime
const newData: NewFormat = {
  foo: "baz",
  bar: 12
}

const oldData: OldFormat = {
  f: "qux",
  b: 17
}

const barMap = {
  12: "TWELVE",
  17: "SEVENTEEN"
}

// The "translation" map can be asserted as const,
// possibly using TS 4.9 `satisfies` operator
// to keep some constraint between old and new formats
const shorthandPropertyMap = {
  foo: "f",
  bar: "b"
} as const satisfies {
    [key in keyof NewFormat]: keyof OldFormat
  }

const getProperty = <P extends keyof typeof shorthandPropertyMap>(
  data: NewFormat | OldFormat,
  prop: P
) => {
  return prop in data
    ? (data as NewFormat)[prop]
    : (data as OldFormat)[shorthandPropertyMap[prop]!];
};

const v = getProperty(newData, "bar")
//    ^? 12 | 17
console.log(barMap[getProperty(oldData, "bar")] === "SEVENTEEN") // Okay
console.log(barMap[getProperty(newData, "bar")] === "TWELVE") // Okay
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20221017#code/PTAEFUGcEsDsHNQBcAWBTUBbA9gJw-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-JBcV0QQKyMGZJAASgSfCr10fAkEaMZQCYptH1IyxdAAflAQjSMDCiJyQNibyE98xNAIxpOhQNfwRRSMPnbCV0g0olJXd8AEJ33KPxp1BSgWVApAcMgwjRzpOhzgxWw0TY55dFAAA9cSbJpNB0wibB4EIiV+BvBynP9ThCMHNyPOKbz3wSNQNDRA0jRNM1vNAaownsOhOGCiJQvCyLou4WKwMMhKXMhaFUq8tiMqy7LFVVDVCuK0ryokIA)

Comment: Hmm... I must have introduced some slight difference as this definitely was not a problem before I introduced the other format. Your second suggestion seems ideal, but would require me upgrading all projects using this module to TS 4.9. Whilst that is on the cards I can't really undertake that as part of this work, so I may have to resort to the workaround for now.

Comment: You can use TS<4.9, just losing the constraint on the converter. In case of typo, it still fails, but somewhere else and the error message is more obscure https://tsplay.dev/wXqv8N